Access DBFS from init script on GCP databricks
I am trying to place one jar into databricks jars before starting cluster and I have tried following approaches:

Placing into GCS bucket and download from there : this is causing init script timeout exception due to internal company cert verifications
Placing into azure repos: not safe
Placing to dbfs and copying from there but this is throwing error saying /dbfs/internal folders do not exists
Why is that we are not able to access it init script?
My databricks version in 14.3 and I am able to access same paths on Azure databricks but not on GCP databricks.

Can someone help on this please!!
I tried following code in init shell script
cp -f /dbfs/databricks/spark_monitoring.zip /databricks/jars


can you use dbfs filestore?

After experimentation, we added a delay of exactly 1.5 minutes and post that we were able to access dbfs
